# Is it possible to force VisualStudio to reload the solution when pulled from IDE the same way like it does when I pull manually from command line?

Tags: gitlab, visual-studio-2022

Visual studio version 17.8.7
We are using gitlab repository for collaboration on the Visual Studio solution. Solution contains 70+ projects.
Scenario of my problem
Developer_A pushes commits which are changing the project build dependencies, or adding new projects. For example adds build dependency of project Y1 on project X1.
Developer_B has the solution open in visual studio and is working on any part of it.
Developer_B wants to commit hist changes and push the commit. It implies pulling and maybe merging.

case 1: manual pull from windows command line. After this pull, VS will show dialog that the files were changed outside of the environment and will ask
whether the solution shall be reloaded or the changes ignored and loaded next time the soluition is open. Choosing the first option causes the VS to reload
solution and when the developer_B checks the project Y1 build dependencies, the new dependency pushed by developer_A will be visible. That is okay, no problem.

case 2: pull from the VS git integration tool: In this case no dialog is shown. Developer_B visually checks the Y1 project build dependency and there is no dependency on project X1 visible. However, checking the solution file on the filesystem shows, that the file itself is updated and does contain the build dependency. If, in this situation developer_B saves his work, then the "in_memory" state of project build dependencies gets persisted to the solution file, and effectively reverts the changes on solution file comming from commit of Developer_A. This is the the problem.

What we would like to achieve is that the Visual Studio will reload the solution when the pull from the gitlab repo changes the solution file and will reflect the changes on the projects or on the project build dependencies.
I believe its possible to automate it, without having manually reload solution or fallback to git pull from command line. Maybe its some setting in the VS git integration but I dont see anything related.

Searching for solution brouight me to posts, where developers were complaining about opposite: too frequent prompts for solution reload when changes were detected. There is a note that from specific version this prompt will be not presented in specific cases - like for example when switching between branches, so maybe its somehow related to that update and its not a bug but a feature?

Is it possible to force the visual studio to reload the solution when git pull from IDE is used to behave the same way like it does when I pull manually from command line?

thank you

Juraj